# display other partial than default.htm in Component onRun method

Tags: octobercms

How to display other partial than `default.htm` in `onRun` component method ?
have to test some stuff and display specific partial according to the result.

*edit:*
Another important point is that one of these partials need specific data, so how to pass them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check some condition in twig and then include the correct partial in your `default.htm`. Example:

```
{% if __SELF__.someCondition %}

    {% partial __SELF__ ~ '::file1' %}

{% else %}

    {% partial __SELF__ ~ '::file2' %}

{% endif %}
```

Where `someCondition` refers to either a member variable of your component or a method. You can even have more complex structures and check for certain values explicitly. Check out the [twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html).

Comment: hmmmm, just a little precision, one partial need dynamic data, how to get them through an intermediate partial ?

Comment: to pass data to the partial, do as usual